# Caused by NewConnectionError : Failed to establish a new connection:

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, web-crawler, screen-scraping

```
df = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx', nrows=114)

# Define a function to extract the URL and URL_ID from a row
def extract_url_id(row):
  return row['URL'], row['URL_ID']

# Apply the function to each row and extract the URL and URL_ID

urls, url_ids = zip(*df.apply(extract_url_id, axis=1))

print(urls)
print(url_ids)

# Extract the URLs from the DataFrame
urls = df['URL'].tolist()

# Iterate over the URLs
for url in urls:
 
 # Make a request to the URL
 
 r = requests.get(url)

  # Extract the HTML from the response

  html = r.text
```

Im trying to get the text from a list of URLs presnt in an input file 'Input.xlsx'
For each of the articles, given in the input.xlsx file, extract the article text and save the extracted article in a text file with URL_ID as its file name.
error typically indicates that there was an issue establishing a connection ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Find a specific URL where the problem appears. If possible mention the URL in the question. Try to access the URL with a browser. Does this work?

Comment: last but one line where I am requesting to the URL is where the error shows, (r=request.get(url)), the URL is working fine. i think its the problem with how im requesting the connection?